# Which staffs will be used by followers, when given to them?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

I've observed followers use staffs that have spells from the Conjuration and Destruction schools of magic only. I am wondering if followers will also use [staffs with spells from the other schools of magic](http://uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Staff#Standard_Staves) or [all of the special staffs](http://uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Staff#Special_Staves).

Which staffs will be used by [followers](http://uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Followers), when given to them? Or alternatively, which staffs will not be used by any [follower](http://uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Followers), when given to them?

[List of all staffs in Skyrim](http://uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Staves) [UESP Wiki article].

Note: [Staffs can't be disenchanted nor custom enchanted.](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/51160/4797)

Answer (score 5):

This is an interesting question. Because of this question, I started giving Lydia all sorts of staffs that I found in my current game. She is using paralysis staff with great enthusiasm on top of the conjuration staffs and destruction staffs, so we will add that to our list. I took away chain lightening staff from her because it's an Area of Effect spell staff and it damages me all the time when she uses it. I gave her a healing staff, but she hasn't used it, yet. I'll give her a fear staff when I find one.

[Edit] I made the test more complete by giving Lydia a whole bunch of staffs I do not remember her using before and going through a couple of caves and bandit camps.

Alteration

- Staff of Magelight: No
- Staff of Paralysis: Yes

Conjuration:Banish

- Staff of Banishing: No
- Staff of Daedric Command: No
- Staff of Expulsion: No

Conjure:Conjure

- Staff of the Familiar: Yes
- Staff of the Flame Atronach
- Staff of the Frost Atronach: Yes
- Staff of the Storm Atronach

Conjuration:Reanimate

- Staff of Zombies: Yes
- Staff of Reanimation
- Staff of Revenants
- Staff of Dread Zombies

Conjuration: Soul Trap

- Staff of Soul Trapping: No

Destruction: Yes

Illusion: No

- Staff of Calm: No
- Grand Staff of Charming: No
- Staff of Fear: No
- Staff of Vanquishment: No
- Staff of Fury: No
- Staff of Frenzy: No
- Staff of Courage: No
- Staff of Inspiration: No

Restoration: Restore Health

- Staff of the Healing Hand: No
- Staff of Mending: No

Restoration: Turn Undead (Not tested yet)

- Grand Staff of Turning
- Grand Staff of Repulsion

Comment: In your tests, do followers use all staffs from all three of those schools of magic? [List of all staffs and the school of magic they're in (link)](http://uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim%3aStaves). I haven't seen followers use the Staff of Magelight (Alteration) or Conjuration staffs with the '[Banish](http://uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim%3aStaves#Banish)' or 'Soul Trap' enchantments. Could you list the individual staffs you've tested?

Comment: @galacticninja thanks for the list. I didn't think to look there. I'll update the list. I had Lydia carry a mage light staff for a long time but she did not use it.

Answer (score -1):

You can make followers use staves that let them heal other things, but I've heard you have to make it be their only staff. Even then they've been caught healing hostiles...

Comment: I've never seen followers use Restoration staffs, and use them to heal hostiles. Can anybody else confirm this? Sheogorath has been known to be quite a jokester. =)